# A word that describes a person who has to fight against a more powerful opponent on a regular basis?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes a person who has to fight against a powerful opponent on a regular basis. **This does not involve a competition**, like some kind of sport.

**Example** :

Lawyers willing to take on powerful companies are hard to find, however James from the law firm  Crane & Schmidt, regularly lock horns against major companies.

So in the above example *what would someone like James be called, who has to regularly fight against companies/entities **that are much more powerful than him***?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've checked the link that you have provided. Consequently I've changed the wordings in the question as well as the example sentence so that members realise what exactly I need. I'm hoping this question is not a possible duplicate.

Comment: If it's still a duplicate, there's a possibility you've already got your answer. But I think you're expecting too much from a single word now.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The link that you have provided refers to a competition. So a word like "underdog" (provided as an answer) is probably the appropriate word.But the scenario I'm referring to does not involve `competition` as such.

Comment: 'Underdog' is obviously metaphorical even when used in a sporting context, and broadening (visualising a legal struggle as say a boxing match) licenses the non-sporting usage.

Comment: Not plane nor bird nor even frog.  It's just little old me -- Underdog!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Giant-slayer*** would work, especially in your requested context.  It works well because it casts a positive spin on the firm's niche place in the market.

> James doesn't want to be known as an underdog...
>
> ...**Jack** wants to be known as a **GIANT-SLAYER**!

(I mean, which would you rather hire if you were up against a huge corporation's lawyers?)

For added panache, perhaps James would be willing to go by Jack? This practice is not uncommon according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_(given_name)) and in 2013, a movie came out called [Jack the Giant Slayer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1351685/) which would mean many people will already associate the name with the label.

Also, [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/78089?redirectedFrom=giant%20slayer#eid3155944) has a reference to the term from the 19th century:

> *giant-slayer*  n.a1878   G. G. Scott Lect. Mediæval Archit. (1879) I.
>   38   The *giant-slayers* of old romance.

Plus, the moniker ***giant killer*** is already taken by another lawyer!  Attorney Willie E. Gary, according to his [website](https://williegary.com/willie-gary),

> "earned the reputation as 'The Giant Killer' by taking down some of
>   America’s most well- known corporate giants on behalf of his clients."

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious answer to me would be **underdog** or possibly **dark horse**.  If a single-word answer isn't required, though, you could also emphasize the long odds *and* the size difference by making reference to [David and Goliath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goliath)--especially since David Hayes shares a common name!

Comment: I've changed the example & the wording of the question to better reflect what I need. Apologies for changing after you have posted an answer.

Comment: Hmmm.  I still think these are the closest available options, especially because you say "_has_ to fight against a powerful opponent".  If you're looking for a word that describes somebody who is always _looking_ for fights with more powerful opponents, there _may_ be a single word out there, but I don't think I know it.